# ROR Capistrano fails deploy at db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, deployment, capistrano

I have to deploy new features to my staging server.
so i run `bundle exec cap staging deploy`, like i always have.

but this time it return me this errors :

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

DEBUG [66e17bbb]    /home/municipiumstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
DEBUG [66e17bbb]    /home/municipiumstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
DEBUG [66e17bbb]    /home/municipiumstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
DEBUG [66e17bbb]    /home/municipiumstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
DEBUG [66e17bbb]    /home/municipiumstage/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
DEBUG [af711402]    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
DEBUG [873c7135]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Someone could explain me what is the problem and maybe how to solve it? thank you!

Comment: Try to reapply new migrations in development mode. Maybe some typo there.

Comment: how i have to do it? sorry but i'm still new of ruby

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back

Comment: bin/rails db:migrate:redo STEP=3 , STEP is a number of migrations you want to rerun

Comment: i have to run this command in my local project?

Comment: yes, on local machine

Comment: and this "bin/rails" wjat is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158388/discussion-between-kolas-and-leonardo).